# want to create a download function with special characters in the file name

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a download function in php in which the file contains special characters in it.
but while downloading the file, the file name breaks from some special characters.
mainly while obtaining a space in file name.
my download function is this.

```
function download(){
            $filename = "google _(){}[]valentine~!@#$%^&*()_+`1=-.flv";
            $filepath = "uploads/" . $filename;
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            //setting content type of page
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            //Read File it will start downloading
            readfile($filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to escape spaces with a "\ ".

Like this:

```
$filename = str_replace( ' ', '\ ', $filename );
```

Comment: thanks.
i did it yesterday itself.
in this way.
`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename."\"");`
thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using urlencode?

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php